# [c++]no matching function to call, expect 2 argument 0provide

Tags: c++

### Got some error with this coding one rectangle class, one inheritance

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle{ //class
private:
    double width;
    double height;
public:
    Rectangle(double width, double height);
    double area();
    double circumference();
    double getWidth();
    double getHeight();
};

class SquareRectangle:public Rectangle//inheritance{
private:
     double side;
public:
     SquareRectangle(double side);
     double getSide();
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(double width, double height){
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}

double Rectangle::area(){
     return (getWidth()*getHeight());
}

double Rectangle::circumference(){
     return ((getWidth()*2)+(getHeight()*2));
}

double Rectangle::getWidth(){
     return width;
}

double Rectangle:: getHeight(){
    return height;
}
SquareRectangle::SquareRectangle(double side){
    this->side = side;
}

double SquareRectangle::getSide(){
    return side;
}
```

and got this error as you can see in this picture
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T9Pw.jpg)

appreciate all the help here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: You have inherited from ractangle and ractangle doesnt have default constructor. You can do it like  SquareRectangle::SquareRectangle(double side) : Rectangle(side,side){
    this->side = side;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for **SquareRectangle** needs to invoke the constructor of its parent class **Rectangle**. The constructor can be coded-up like so:

```
SquareRectangle::SquareRectangle(double side)
: Rectangle(side, side) {
    this->side = side;
}
```